# Cannot build project 'Simplify' with gradle

Tags: java, android, simplify

I am trying to build the project 'Simplify' from github (https://github.com/CalebFenton/simplify). I have downloaded the files and ran the command in command prompt:

```
gradle build
```

But the build fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE:Build failed with an exception
*What went wrong:
>Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':demoapp:compile'
Required by org.cf:demoapp:1.0.0
>Could not resolve org.skf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.7
>Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.7/slf4j-nop-1.7.7.pom'
>Failure inintializing default system SSL context
```

....etc

What am I doing wrong? 
I have internet connected during the build. I am using Java SE 8u74 and gradle 2.10.

P.S- When I tried to run the gradle wrapper by the command:

```
gradlew fatjar
```

It gives many errors.

Comment: The library could not be found. Are you including mavenCentral() in your repositories?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Sorry for making a typo. The library link is now corrected. (By the way, I don't think that it has something to do with library. I think their is a problem with the way java is trying to access the internet.) When I used java 7 it did not give any error for building projects, but I had to use java 8 for building this project. And then all problems started. The problem has something to do with SSL.

Comment: have you seen this discussion: seem like some people have had probs with cacerts with gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/failure-initializing-default-system-ssl-context/6568/5